# Don't execute a keydown function if some divs are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, keydown

My script execute some actions (like stop one audio player) in case the user press the space bar:

```
$('html').keydown(function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 32){
       // Stop the audio player
   }
}
```

But the problem comes when a user tries to write a message in the textarea because the previous function executes (and it's very annoying)... How can I do to not execute the function, in case the user is writing a message on a textarea or other elements?

Comment: Remove the event handler from `html` in `onfocus` handler of `textarea`. Then assign it back in `onblur` handler.

Comment: I agree with @Teemu alternatively you can look at `e.target` and check whether it is your textarea and then not do anything if it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip when user is focussing some control, this example will prevent the player to stop if user i typing in a text area.

```
$(function () {
            $(document).keypress(function (e, f) {

                var tagName = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
                if (tagName != 'textarea') {
                    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
                        console.log('Stop Playing');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Hopw this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#textAreaId').keypress(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This hardly is what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the sender of the event, if the sender is other controls then the audio player then ignore the call, otherwise stop the player.

```
$('html').keydown(function(e){
   var senderID = $(event.target).attr('id');
   if(senderID == 'myAudioPlayerID' && e.keyCode == 32){
       // Stop the audio player
   }
}
```

Comment: If event comes from a child element of #myAudioPlayerID this code fails probably. But you check also if there is parent with id of myAudioPlayerID then it works. But he wants play to stop when user press spacebar outside of the player also probably.

Comment: Another approach can be to check if the keysroke came from an input field tag or a textarea field tag

Answer (score 0):

Use ***stopPropagation*** method on event object when space bar pressed on textarea.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testTextArea").keydown(function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 32){
           e.stopPropagation();
       }
    });

    $("#container").keydown(function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 32){
           alert('Player Stoped/Started')
       }
    });
})
```

**fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/b0u3z8pg/16/

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**  :)

```
$('html').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
        // stop the music player
    }
});
$('input, textarea').keydown(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

The code inside the if statement only triggers if you are not focused inside a text area or input.

<kbd>[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/Ls55pLdw/)</kbd>

HTML:

```
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="text">
```

jQuery:

```
var exclude = $("textarea, input");

$('html').on("keydown", function( e ) {

    if ( e.keyCode == 32 && !exclude.is(':focus') ) {
       console.log( 'Space pressed outside input or text area' );
    }

});
```

Comment: Oh yeah. I rewrote the code with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, but you don't need to do that, if your jquery version doesn't allow. Also, [:focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) was brought in at version 1.6.